# Amazon fire tv carousel

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

Is their anyway way to implement carousel for amazon fire TV.
As i implemented carousel it works fine on phone but when i tried to create it for fire TV.Is their any other way to implement carousel and access the position of every image in carousel and highlight it
    //here is the Java code

```
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.KeyEvent;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.digitalaria.gama.carousel.Carousel;
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
            private Carousel carousel;
            private ImageAdapter adapter;

        private int[] musicCover = { R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_15,
                    R.drawable.pic_2, R.drawable.pic_8, R.drawable.pic_9,
                    R.drawable.pic_1,R.drawable.pic_15,R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_15,
                    R.drawable.pic_2, R.drawable.pic_8, R.drawable.pic_9,
                    R.drawable.pic_1,R.drawable.pic_15
                    };

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            init();
        }
        private void init()
        {
             // create the carousel object.
            carousel = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),carousel.getAngle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            carousel.setType(Carousel.TYPE_CYLINDER);
            carousel.setOverScrollBounceEnabled(true);
            carousel.setInfiniteScrollEnabled(true);
            carousel.setItemRearrangeEnabled(true);
            carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                        Log.d("test", "test");
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
                // ... handle selections
                        Log.d("test", "test");
                        //handled = true;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                // ... handle left action
                        Log.d("test", "test");
                        //handled = true;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                // ... handle right action
                        Log.d("test", "test");
                        //handled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switch (keyCode){
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                                Log.d("test", "test");
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
                        // ... handle selections
                                Log.d("test", "test");
                                //handled = true;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                        // ... handle left action
                                Log.d("test", "test");
                                //handled = true;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                        // ... handle right action
                                Log.d("test", "test");
                                //handled = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.d("OnItem ","click"+"position="+position+" id="+id);

                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("OnItem ","click"+"position="+position+" id="+id);

                }
            });
            carousel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),carousel.getAngle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                }
            });

            // set images for the carousel.
            adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            carousel.setAdapter(adapter);

            // change the first selected position.
            //carousel.setCenterPosition(3);
        }
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c)
            {
                mContext = c;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                  return musicCover.length;
            }

            @Override`enter code here`
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return musicCover[position];
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.carousel_item, parent, false);                
                    view.setLayoutParams(new Carousel.LayoutParams(250, 250));

                    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

                    view.setTag(holder);
                    holder.imageView.setFocusable(true);

                }

                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(musicCover[position]);
                holder.imageView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keycode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        boolean handled = false;

                        switch (keycode){
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                                Log.d("test UP", "test UP");
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                        // ... handle selections
                                Log.d("test down", "test Down");
                                handled = true;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                        // ... handle left action
                                Log.d("test left", "test left");
                                handled = true;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                        // ... handle right action
                                Log.d("test right", "test right");
                                handled = true;
                                break;
                            }
             //return handled || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        //}
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                return view;
            }

            private class ViewHolder {
                ImageView imageView;
            }


        }
    }

XML FILES activity main

    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.crouselexample.MainActivity" >

        <com.digitalaria.gama.carousel.Carousel
            android:id="@+id/carousel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


for image xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Is their any solution or any other way?

Comment: "...it works fine on phone but when i tried to create it for fire TV." When you tried what happened?

Comment: You are not using a standard android component for the carousel. I suggest you reach out to the Digitalaria forum http://developer.digitalaria.com/forum/

Answer (score 1):

I would use leanback support library. They have nice carousel support (RowsFragment). Most leanback implementations are supported on fire TV. However there are some implementations that are not supported (I.e. search fragment).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/package-summary

amazon documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/differences-from-android-tv-development.html#leanback-support-library

Card presenter example:

```
public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {

private static final String TAG = CardPresenter.class.getSimpleName();

private static Context mContext;
private static int CARD_WIDTH = 313;
private static int CARD_HEIGHT = 176;

static class ViewHolder extends Presenter.ViewHolder {
    private Movie mMovie;
    private ImageCardView mCardView;
    private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mCardView = (ImageCardView) view;
        mDefaultCardImage = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.movie);
    }

    public void setMovie(Movie m) {
        mMovie = m;
    }

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return mMovie;
    }

    public ImageCardView getCardView() {
        return mCardView;
    }

    public Drawable getDefaultCardImage() {
        return mDefaultCardImage;
    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(mContext);
    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.fastlane_background));
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    Movie movie = (Movie) item;
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setMovie(movie);

    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mCardView.setTitleText(movie.getTitle());
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mCardView.setContentText(movie.getStudio());
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mCardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mCardView.setMainImage(((ViewHolder) viewHolder).getDefaultCardImage());
}

@Override
public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbindViewHolder");
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    // TO DO
}
```

}

MainFragment example:

```
private void loadRows() {
    mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
    ...

    /* CardPresenter */
    HeaderItem cardPresenterHeader = new HeaderItem(1, "CardPresenter");
    CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter cardRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle("title" + i);
        movie.setStudio("studio" + i);
        cardRowAdapter.add(movie);
    }
    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(cardPresenterHeader, cardRowAdapter));

     //add code
}
```

Comment: @Zoe sorry i dont have to much experience with answering on here... is this better?

Comment: yep. Retracted my flag.